# Rails wont render a RestClient exception body unless I interpolate it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a really weird issue trying to write a test around a rails controller.
The controller uses `RestClient` to get info from another server. If that 2nd server returns a bad response, I want to forward on that error message to the client.

The controller:

```
def callback_submit
  begin
    response = RestClient.post(...)
    render json: response
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
    render status: :bad_request, json: { error: e.response.body }
  end
end
```

Then I have an rspec test for this:

```
  it 'returns a failure message' do
    stub_request( :post, 'http://...' ).to_return( status: 400, body: 'some error' )

    post :callback_submit

    expect(response.body).to eq({error: 'some error'}.to_json)
  end
```

---

Now the problem is that the rspec output is:

```
   expected: "{\"error\":\"some error\"}"
        got: "{\"error\":\"\"}"
```

---

Where it gets weird is that I can change my controller to `puts` some details...

```
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
    error = e.response.body.to_s
    puts error.class
    puts error
    render status: :bad_request, json: { error: error }
```

Which outputs:

```
String
some error

   expected: "{\"error\":\"some error\"}"
        got: "{\"error\":\"\"}"
```

So the `error` variable seems to be a string and the correct value, but `render` turns it into an empty string.

---

Now it gets really weird... If I interpolate the string:

```
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
    error = e.response.body.to_s
    puts error.class
    puts error
    render status: :bad_request, json: { error: "#{error}" }
```

Or just simply:

```
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
    render status: :bad_request, json: { error: "#{e.response.body}" }
```

Then my test PASSES!

---

At first I thought `e.response.body` must not be a String, which is why I `puts` its `class` which prints "String" and also called `.to_s` on it, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Can anyone explain this weird behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Asked some Ruby friends and one of them found the problem, but didn't want to come post an answer here....

---

The problem ends up being that we are on an older `RestClient` (1.8). [In the RestClient 2.0 notes](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/45adc5e3b5032002ab6ad971ee099b3b4254f77d/history.md):

> Response objects are now a subclass of String rather than a String that mixes in the response functionality.
>
> Response#body and #to_s will now return a true String object rather than self. Previously there was no easy way to get the true String response instead of the Frankenstein response string object with AbstractResponse mixed in.

So in the older version I am using, `e.response` ends up being this weird String mixin mashup thing, and `render` doesn't seem to like it.

The interpolation turns it back into a real Ruby string again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `response.body` is looking at the response object and the body is empty because of the error.

Chances are you want `e.message` or just `e.to_s` which will be the error message (or the error class name) rather than the response body.

Excerpt:

```
class Exception < RuntimeError
  attr_accessor :response
  attr_writer :message
  #.......
  def to_s
    message
  end

  def message
    @message || default_message
  end

  def default_message
    self.class.name
  end
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/exceptions.rb#L109)

Comment: `e.to_s` is "400 Bad Request". Also the body isn't empty. I `puts` it and it does contain my string from the rspec.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike what is the expected result as I doubt it is "some error"

Comment: It is that, just a different string. actually a validation error message. Figured out the issue... going to answer own question in a moment...